Pushouts vs contractible colimits
Suppose that $C$ has all weakly contractible colimits, i.e. colimits of functors $F: I \rightarrow C$ where the geometric realization $|I|$ is weakly contractible. Then $C$ has pushouts and filtered colimits.
I am interested in whether the converse holds: if $C$ has pushouts and filtered colimits, does $C$ have all weakly contractible colimits?
Edit: I am generally interested in the case when $C$ is an $\infty$-category.

are you asking about 1-categories or about infty-categories?

infty-categories; I can add a comment about this.

The answer is yes. Let  $C$ be a weakly contractible quasicategory. We wish to show that a category with pushouts and filtered colimits has $C$ colimits. Let $\Delta^0 \to C$ be the inclusion of your favorite object. By the small object argument, we can factor this as $\Delta^0 \to X \to C$ where the first map is cellularly anodyne and then the second is a trivial fibration. So any $C$-indexed diagram pulls back to an $X$-indexed one whose colimit is the same and we may assume that $C=X$ so the inclusion $\Delta^0 \to C$ is cellularly anodyne.
Since the colimit of a diagram indexed by a colimit of categories is the colimit of the colimits, and because cellularly anodyne maps are built by transfinite composition (a filtered colimit) and cobase change (a pushout) from horn inclusions $\Lambda_k^n \to \Delta^n$, it will suffice to construct colimits indexed by $\Lambda_k^n$ and $ \Delta^n$ using pushouts. The latter is trivial (evaluation at the terminal object) and so is the former in the inner anodyne case. Colimits indexed by $\Lambda_2^2$ are trivial and those indexed by $\Lambda_0^2$ are literally pushouts. Higher horns are built from lower ones using pushouts and cones as $\Lambda^{n+1}_k =  \Delta^0 * \Lambda^n_k \cup_{\Lambda^n_k} \Delta^n$, so it now suffices to observe that $A \to \Delta^0 * A$ is final when $A$ is weakly contractible. So inductively we do get all these colimits.

I may have messed up treatment of retracts but note that the walking idempotent is filtered.

I am confused about how you used the fact that C is weakly contractible. Is it to conclude that X→C
is a trivial fibration? You use that A is weakly contractible at the end of the argument, but this seems to be for a different purpose (to let you go from Λnk
to Λn+1k, which I think one can prove directly).

@user39598 Yes, for arbitrary $C$ we can factor $\Delta^0 \to C$ either as $\Delta^0 \to X \to C$ where the first map is anodyne and the second is a Kan fibration, or as $\Delta^0 \to Y \to C$ where the first map is a monomorphism and the second map is a trivial fibration. Given that $C$ is weakly contractible, though, we can deduce (by 2-for-3) that when we do this it will turn out that $X \to C$ is a trivial fibration and $\Delta^0 \to Y$ is anodyne.
